# How to preview text in all available font family?

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, macros, formatting, word-processing

Assume my PC has 100 fonts. I want to write "Hello World" in all available fonts at once in any text editor/word processor, how can I do it?

I will input only a string and output will be preview of that string in all available font family.

I am open to use VB macro, MS office app, HTML/CSS/JS, other 3rd party app or any other solution. I don't want to waste my time to check how `Lorem Ipsum` or `Quick Brown Fox...` looks.

Thanks!

Comment: You can do it in Excel: Enter your text in A1, in A2 enter the formula `=A1`, then fill it down as many time as many fonts you've installed. Change each cells' font to a different one and you're done. If you change your text in your A1 cell, then it'll change in all others, and you'll see it with different fonts. Second part of your question is off-topic here, either because it asks for software recommendation either it's too broad (asking specific question on macros is fine, but answering entire macro solutions is out of scope).

Answer (score 0):

See this link for macro to create a 2 column table with font name, and example text in that font.  Just modify the example text to "Hello World".

http://members.shaw.ca/bayswater/pages/hotspots/fontmacro.htm